# PHP get post button through ajax

Tags: php, ajax

In **product-master.php** (view page), I have a few buttons: Add, Edit, Delete.

Each button got unique name: **btnAddProduct**, **btnEditProduct**, **btnDelProduct**

These buttons share the same action page *as shown in the ajax code below*: **action/product-master.php** (yes I named it according to the view page, just different folder)

Yes, I'm using ajax method to process form data. How to validate which button was pressed?

I tried using `isset($_POST['btnAddProduct'])` but it is not working. Below is my button:

**btnAddProduct**

`<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnAddProduct" name="btnAddProduct">`

**product-master.php**

```
$('#btnAddProduct').on('click', function(e) {
    var formData = new FormData($('#form-add-modal')[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: "action/<?php echo basename(__FILE__); ?>",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(){
            //Display error here
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buttons aren't included when you create a `FormData` from a form, since the `FormData` constructor has no way of knowing which button was clicked. You need to add it to the `FormData` explicitly.

```
$('#btnAddProduct').on('click', function(e) {
    var formData = new FormData($('#form-add-modal')[0]);
    formData.set(this.name, "1");
    $.ajax({
        url: "action/<?php echo basename(__FILE__); ?>",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(){
            //Display error here
        }
    });
});
```